# Find columns based on contents of respective first rows

Tags: bash, awk, grep, columns

So I have a `TSV` file that looks something like this:

```
Hello world how are you
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

(I've separated everything within each row with a single whitespace in the hand-written toy example above.)

My objective is to get the columns that contain "how" and "are" as the first row values. The output, therefore, would look like this:

```
how are
3 4
8 9
```

The problem is that I do not know which column these patterns (i.e., "how" and "are") will occur. So, for example, the `TSV` file could actually be arranged like this:

```
Hello how world are you
1 3 2 4 5
6 8 7 9 0
```

I know how I can deal with this in, say, something like `python` (just transpose the file, and then select the rows I want) but I'd like to do it in the shell (for reasons). The problem is, I don't know how to. I know that transposition is also possible using command line utilities (e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash)) but I'd like to avoid that bulky code if I can. My initial, simple-minded solution was to just `grep` "how" and "are" but that obviously returned the entire file, and that's where I've been stuck since.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Edit: I must mention, I do not have privileges to install any new tools on this machine. I am also quite uncertain what it actually comes with. If it helps, this is `Scientific Linux 7.3 (Nitrogen)`.

Comment: You want to do this in the shell, but you've tagged this with [awk] and [grep]? Which one do you mean? With just the shell, or with standard utilities, or... what?

Comment: @ilkkachu well, standard utilities would be fine by me. Basically with just whatever is available (see my edit). I know this is a bit nebulous, and I apologize for that.

Comment: it's just that with text processing, awk is seriously useful, but it's not the same as just the shell. Even Busybox has awk, but one might still have some weird context where it's actually _only the shell_ that's available. So it's necessary to know what's available.

Answer (score 3):

Use `csvtool`¹:

```
csvtool -t ' ' -u ' ' namedcol how,are file
```

---

```
-t Input separator char.
-u Output separator char.

 namedcol <names>
    Assuming the first row of the CSV file is a list of column headings,
    this returned the column(s) with the named headings.
```

---

¹ `sudo apt install csvtool`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is, this machine doesn't come with `csvtool`, and I can't install anything on it either. I didn't realize I should have mentioned this in the OP. I apologize for wasting your time!

Comment: No problem, I'll leave the answer though if anyone else needs it.

Comment: Thank you for being understanding. And I've learned about `csvtool` from your answer (and a tool like this is something I'd use elsewhere in the future), so it was not in vain!

Answer (score 3):

Via `awk` you can check the first row for matching keywords, note down the column number, then print the respective values:

```
#first line -> Select columns based on keyword
NR==1 {
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if ( $i == "how" ) {col_how=i}
    if ( $i == "are" ) {col_are=i}
  }
}
#print selected columns including header line
NR>=1 {
  print $col_how, $col_are
}
```

Save as e.g. `script.awk` and execute

```
awk -f script.awk datafile
```

---

EDIT:

Also your idea of transposing and `grep`ing can be realized easily:

```
datamash transpose <datafile | grep 'how\|are' | datamash transpose
```

use `-t ' '` to define spaces as separators. Nevertheless on very long files this might run into RAM limits. However might not be installed by standard on most machines.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    cols = (cols == "" ? "how are" : cols)
    nf = split(cols,tgts)
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[tgts[i]]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
how     are
3       4
8       9
```

.

```
$ awk -v cols='are world you Hello' -f tst.awk file
are     world   you     Hello
4       2       5       1
9       7       0       6
```

Comment: Nice work. This works as described above. Curious how you could use this approach to achieve which columns should be excluded vs included? I have a case where there are about 50 columns and I want filter out a few columns by column header name value vs knowing the position ahead of time.

Comment: @Streamline Thank you. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Ed, I will if I can't figure it out from your work here. Maybe some comments in your answer about what some of the key pieces of the awk script are doing would enhance the answer for myself and others trying to learn from it.

Comment: It's all stuff you could learn just from the man pages and/or adding a few prints to dump anything you're not sure of plus it's 2 years old so I'm not real inspired to come back to revisit it now, sorry. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.